# Reformatting separated char to couples

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Input:

```
rs001 A C T G C G T T
rs002 C C T T G G A A
```

out1:

```
rs001 AC TG CG TT
rs002 CC TT GG AA
```

out2 :

```
rs001 1 1 1 2
rs002 2 2 2 2
```

Ok so basically I want to replace any two similar nucleotides (like AA, CC, TT, or GG) to 2 and any two different (like AT, TA, CG, .. etc) to 1 taking into account that the input should be converted first to out1 then to out2. Also we have so many fields (like 200 columns) in each row, so loops are needed here.

This is what I tried:

```
cat input | awk '{ for (x = 2; x <= NF; x = x+2) print $x$(x+1) }'
```

Results are so weird, so can anyone please tell me why I can't get out1 ?! What mistakes I did in awk loops ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: UUOC. awk can open files just as easily as "cat" can.

Comment: I know that but I keep using cat to make the pipeline easily read from left to right :)

Comment: If you want a hack just to make it read left to right then use `< input awk '...'`. You do NOT need cat. In both cases, though, you're sacrificing the FILENAME variable and it's just not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you fix your `awk` script to get output 1:

```
awk '{ printf "%s ", $1; for (x = 2; x <= NF; x = x + 2) {printf "%s%s ", $x, $(x+1)} printf "\n"}' input
```

`print` adds a new line at the end by default, so you'll have to use formatted strings `printf` to specify where exactly you want the new lines.

(Also added `printf "%s ", $1;` at the start to print the header at the start of each line)

Edit: Triplee's solution looks much more elegant than mine - you should ditch awk and go with his =)

Comment: I'd stick with awk in case there's a requirements change to make the test case-insensitive or handle variable numbers/types of spaces between fields, or print line numbers or any of a million other simple requirements changes that would require just a minor tweak in an awk solution but a total re-write of a sed solution.

Comment: I will choose your answer because it taught me how to solve the bug in my script, and this is the purpose of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

For the first,

```
sed 's/ \([ACGT]\) / \1/g' input >out1
```

This will remove the space after every other nucleitude. It matches a nucleotide with a space on both sides; the next match will pick up where the previous ended.

For the second,

```
sed 's/\([ACGT]\)\1/2/g;s/[ACGT][ACGT]/1/g' out1 >out2
```

This replaces two adjacent identical letters with 2, then any remaining adjacent two letters with 1.

This assumes you have Linux; other `sed` dialects may require minor modifications.

Comment: Actually I used your second part and sampson-chen's first part. I am not sure if I can choose more than one best answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{
   out1 = out2 = $1
   for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
      out1 = out1 FS $i $(i+1)
      out2 = out2 FS ($i == $(i+1) ? 2 : 1)
   }
   print out1 > "out1"
   print out2 > "out2"
}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re 's/ (.) / \1/g;w out1' -e 's/([ACTG])\1/2/g;s/[ACTG]./1/g' file >out2
```